# What should I do if a question is closed before I finish my answer?

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

Today, I was in the middle of answering a question, but was interrupted by a notification that it's closed (off-topic, but it was about programming, despite the fact it was poorly asked* it requested something that could be done in numerous ways), and no more answers can be posted. The question may be able to be salvaged.

What should *I* do if I have already started an answer (that I felt was succinct and would be helpful to OP and maybe others) and it closes? It's a problem that happens often it seems.

I didn't want to trash my answer, but I didn't feel like fighting to reopen the question (at least right now). Personally, I felt the close was just too fast, as the OP may have first posted the question and then gone to get some code to add or something.

Should answers be allowed to be submitted, as long as the question is less than 5 or 10 minutes old, even if they are submitted after it closes? Of course, if this was done, I would keep the alert for closed question, and also add a disclaimer that you are answering a closed question and your answer probably won't be around unless you fix the question. That way, the OP has an answer, at least, and if the question is fixed and reopened, people don't need to redo their work.

Could we allow answers to be "submitted" to closed questions in such a way that they are only visible to the author? If the question reopens, you should get a notification and after editing your answer, it would become visible to all.

---

By "poor quality" I meant they had misspellings and other English problems. It was very obvious what they meant, however.

---

Note there is a similar [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299702/what-should-be-done-with-my-answer-to-this-closed-question) that is asking about *already* submitted answers.

There is also a very similar [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310144/questions-being-closed-as-answers-are-being-written), but I'm trying to ask for a different solution to the problem (I understand the system used to simply have a grace period, but for some reason it was changed to disable the button). I am aware, from that page that there may be hacks in the HTML that let you submit (found unfortunately too late to help me this time).

Bear with me, I'm new and I might be missing something.

Comment: If the **question** is salvaged post your answer then...if it can't  be edited into shape, or isn't, then there is little value in an answer to a question that will be gone eventually.

Comment: As was said in your linked questions *"If it is a question that can be closed quickly, it is best not to attempt to answer it. If the question was answerable, edit it to clarify, then it will be reviewed for reopening and you can post your answer."*

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't have that good a sense what _can be closed quickly_ yet. I've only been here a week.

Comment: @Laurel And yet you've specifically said that you felt that the question is a bad question, and that you knew this before trying to answer it, so at least in this case you *did* know that you shouldn't have tried to answer it.

Comment: @Servy see my edit, I should have been clearer to start with.

Answer (score 6):

> the fact it was poorly asked

Since you knew it was poorly asked, you shouldn't have tried to answer it.

> The question may be able to be salvaged.

If it is salvaged, then it can be reopened.

> What should I do if I have already started an answer and it closes?

Since you seem to feel that the question merits closure, you shouldn't have started writing an answer in the first place.  You can either help the OP improve the question such that it merits reopening, or you can move on and find a *quality* question to answer.

> It's a problem that happens to everyone it seems.

No, pretty much just to people that answer questions they know are bad and merit closure.  The rest of us that spend our time answering *quality* questions don't really have this problem.

> Personally, I felt the close was just too fast, as the OP may have first posted the question and then gone to get some code to add or something.

Again, if they fix their question, it can be reopened.  It's *appropriate* to close the question as soon as possible if it merits closure.  It prevents people like you from posting low quality answers to low quality questions before those questions can be made clear and answerable.

> Should answers be allowed to be submitted, as long as the question is less than 5 or 10 minutes old, even if they are submitted after it closes?

No.  The whole point of closing questions is specifically to prevent answers.  It would defeat the whole point of closing questions to begin with.

Comment: By "poor quality" I meant the spelling/grammar, see my edit.  I also felt that I was writing a high-quality, helpful answer (please don't be mean to me).

Comment: @Laurel Then work to improve the question such that it merits being open.

Comment: What should I do about everything I've written already as an answer, in that case?

Comment: @Laurel If you think you can help the OP turn the question into a quality question that merits reopening, then by all means save your answer until that happens.

Comment: Does SO save my answer for me?

Comment: @Laurel If you didn't post it, no.

Comment: @Laurel You've got the order backwards, that's all. If you see a question that looks like poo, but you can decipher the meaning well enough to be able to answer it, edit the question into shape first (in your case, suggest an edit), *then* answer. If you do that, the question may never even get closed, and other users who would have skipped over it completely may decide to answer it, too.